Connection failed: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc
When I am running an app script from google sheets extensions , I am facing the above error. I already whitelisted the google Ip's and configured all of the setting mentioned in the documentation. I am using a Microsoft SQL server in my office network. Please help me to resolve the issue.
function testDatabaseConnectionA() {

  var url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://<myip>:1433;databaseName=<mydbname>';
  var user = 'myusername';
  var password = 'mypassword';
  
  try {
    Logger.log('Attempting to connect...');
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, password);
    Logger.log('Connection successful!');
    conn.close();
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Connection failed: ' + e.message);
  }
}

this the code I've tried and getting the below error
Connection failed: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc.

No doubt you've read Google App Script: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc and the answer by @Cooper. So, a belt and braces question: your IP isn't 127.0.0.1 is it?

Oops, and its a "public" IP too?

No, my server IP is different, and I already whitelisted the google server IPs using the firewall inbound rule.  When I am trying to connect my server in JavaScript through my own PC in my office network is working fine. but it is not working from google app script.
